# What does Java RuntimeException enableSuppression parameter do ?

Tags: java, exception

I don't know how to say that I've been working with Java for 4 years now and for the first time I encounter this parameter `enableSuppression` can someone explain what does it do and when to enable/disable it ?

Answer (score 8):

`enableSuppression` is a parameter in the constructor of `Throwable`s (including `Exception`)

It determines whether or not suppression is enabled.

From [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed-java.lang.Throwable-):

> The suppression behavior is enabled unless disabled via a constructor.
>
> Note that when one exception causes another exception, the first
>   exception is usually caught and then the second exception is thrown in
>   response. In other words, there is a causal connection between the two
>   exceptions. In contrast, there are situations where two independent
>   exceptions can be thrown in sibling code blocks, in particular in the
>   try block of a try-with-resources statement and the compiler-generated
>   finally block which closes the resource. In these situations, only one
>   of the thrown exceptions can be propagated. In the try-with-resources
>   statement, when there are two such exceptions, the exception
>   originating from the try block is propagated and the exception from
>   the finally block is added to the list of exceptions suppressed by the
>   exception from the try block. As an exception unwinds the stack, it
>   can accumulate multiple suppressed exceptions.
>
> An exception may have suppressed exceptions while also being caused by
>   another exception. Whether or not an exception has a cause is
>   semantically known at the time of its creation, unlike whether or not
>   an exception will suppress other exceptions which is typically only
>   determined after an exception is thrown.
>
> Note that programmer written code is also able to take advantage of
>   calling this method in situations where there are multiple sibling
>   exceptions and only one can be propagated.